# Code Variables vs. Application and Session Variables

Tags: asp-classic, global-variables, application-variables

With respect to classic ASP, are variables defined within individual code files, such as `Const var1 = "foo"`, and so on, maintained per-user or per-server/web-site?  In other words, is it more efficient to define global or public variables (for use by all site users) as Application variables, or does it matter as far as performance and speed are concerned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables are per-request.

Session variables are per-user in a website.

Application variables are for the whole application (i.e website).

Note that on a busy site, overuse of session variables leads to memory pressure (it isn't very efficient), so usage should be kept to a minimum.